# How Can I get first element from API array

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React and API. Here I am fetching data from API.I am trying to do on click button one user should appear. Or on click of user name all other user info should appear. I want to display one element from API array.If click on button new user should show. How to get only one user or one user info. Botton  I added input box which can shoe only one value. I am stuck here.

```
  import React  from 'react';
    import './App.css';
        class Home extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props)
        
                this.state = {
                    items: [],
                    error: '',
                    email:'',
                    phone:'',
                    companyName:''
                }
            this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
            this.showUserEmail = this.showUserEmail.bind(this);
            }
        
            handleInputChange(event){
                const target = event.target;
                const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
                const name = target.name;
            
                this.setState({
                  [name]: value
                 
                });
              }
            handleSelectUserName = (event) => {
                console.log(event.target.value);
                const myUser = (event.target.value);
                this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
                const selectedUser= event.target.value;
              }
              showUserEmail=(e)=>{
                  console.log("you are clicking name" );
                  this.setState({
        
                  })
        
              }
              componentDidMount() {
                fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
                  .then((res) => res.json())
                  .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                    console.warn(result);
                    this.setState({ items: result });
                  });
              }
            
              
        
          render() {
              const { items } = this.state
              return (
             
                  <div>
                      <button className="btn"> Show new User</button>  
                      
<div className="new-user" onChange={event => this.        handleSelectNewUser(event)}>
                          {this.state.items.map(items => (
                          <span key={items.name} value={items.name}>
                              {items.name} <p></p></span>))}
            </div>
<p className="para-text"> Data from API</p>
        
        
                    <div className="user-info">
                      {
                         items.length ?
                         items.map(items => <div key ={ items.id }> 
                          <div className="user-details"> {items.name} </div>
                          <div className="user-details">{items.phone}</div> 
                           <div className="user-details">{items.company.name}</div>
        
                            <div className="user-details">{items.username}</div>
                          <div className="user-details">{items.email}</div>
                          <div className="user-details">{items.website}</div>
                         
                          </div>) : null
                      }
                    </div>
                      <h2>Find User By Username</h2>
                      <div className="input-box">
                              <select onChange={event => this.handleSelectUserName(event)}>
                              {this.state.items.map(items => (
                              <option key={items.name} value={items.name}>
                                  {items.username}
                                </option>
                              ))}
                            </select> 
                            {/* Auto select */}
                       <div className=" Show-User-Auto">    
                            <div className="input-box">
                                <input type="text"
                                placeholder=" Auto Select"
                                required="required"
                                onChange={event => this.handleInputChange(event)}
                                value={this.state.name} />
                            </div>
                        </div>    
                      
                          
                  </div>
                  
            </div>
              );
          }
        }
        export default Home;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve , you need to click on user and you need userinfo to be displayed ?

Comment: Yes, Click on user name and other user details should display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to maintain a state which contains userId , then you can condition render it like below code

```
import React from "react";

class Users extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [],
      error: "",
      email: "",
      phone: "",
      companyName: "",
      userId: "",
      orgList: []
    };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.showUserEmail = this.showUserEmail.bind(this);
  }

  handleSetUserId = (userId) => {
    if (userId === this.state.userId) {
      this.setState({ userId: "" });
    } else {
      this.setState({ userId });
    }
  };

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }
  handleSelectUserName = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    const myUserId = event.target.value;

    if (myUserId) {
      console.log(this.state.orgList, "this.state.orgList");
      let selectedUser = this.state.orgList.filter((item) => {
        return item.id == Number(myUserId);
      });

      console.log(selectedUser, "selectedUser");
      this.setState({ items: selectedUser });
    }
  };
  showUserEmail = (e) => {
    console.log("you are clicking name");
    this.setState({});
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        console.warn(result);
        this.setState({ items: result, orgList: result });
      });
  }

handleFetchAllUsers=()=>{
this.setState({items:this.state.orgList})
}

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="btn" onClick={()=>this.handleFetchAllUsers()}> Show All User</button>

        <div
          className="new-user"
          onChange={(event) => this.handleSelectNewUser(event)}
        >
          {this.state.items.map((items) => (
            <span key={items.name}>
              <br />
              <span onClick={() => this.handleSetUserId(items.id)}>
                {items.name}
                <br />
              </span>

              {items.id === this.state.userId && (
                <p>
                  <br />

                  <div className="user-details">{items.phone}</div>
                  <div className="user-details">{items.company.name}</div>

                  <div className="user-details">{items.username}</div>
                  <div className="user-details">{items.email}</div>
                  <div className="user-details">{items.website}</div>
                </p>
              )}
            </span>
          ))}
        </div>
        <p className="para-text"> Data from API</p>

        <h2>Find User By Username</h2>
        <div className="input-box">
          <select onChange={(event) => this.handleSelectUserName(event)}>
            {this.state.orgList.map((items) => (
              <option key={items.name} value={items.id}>
                {items.username}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          {/* Auto select */}
          <div className=" Show-User-Auto">
            <div className="input-box">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder=" Auto Select"
                required="required"
                onChange={(event) => this.handleInputChange(event)}
                value={this.state.name}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Users;
```

I have implemented the same in codesandbox you can use for ref

[image: Edit busy-elion-edzsk]